# Error while starting iPython notebook

Tags: pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I had ipython notebook working fine. I tried to use Pycharm in remote mode and then it updated some bunch of stuff. Now, when I'm trying to start ipython, I get following error:

```
darshan:~$ ipython notebook Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1168, in <module>
    class MarkerEvaluation(object):   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1174, in MarkerEvaluation
    'platform_version': platform.version, AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'version'
```

I tried to re-install ipython notebook. But the error persists. Does anyone else seen this before or know a fix ?

Comment: wild guess: may be solved by updating setuptools

Answer (score 0):

1) Try reinstalling Python.

2) I highly recommend using [virtual environments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).
They keep your various development environments "clean" and you won't have to worry about conflicts between dependencies.  For instance, you could have one environment for data analysis (with scipy, matplotlib, scikitlearn, etc., which you'd run in IPython Notebook) and others for each app you're developing (for which you would presumably be using PyCharm).